# How to change value of select box to the last option through jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have one select box in which options and its values will be fetched from PHP database.
The last option will be "New Address".

**HTML**

```
<select name="shipping_address_id" id="shipping_customer_address" class="customer_address" title="" onchange="shipping.newAddress(!this.value)">
     <option value="48" selected="selected">p p, yui, cfg,  90602-1234, U.S. Minor Outlying Islands</option>
     <option value="52" selected="selected">e B, ewri, csdfwefg,  90602-1234, U.S. Minor Outlying Islands</option>
     <option value="">New Address</option>
</select>
```

**What I Need**

```
function showForm(){
 jQuery("#shipping_customer_address").val("New Address"); //Not working
}
```

this show showForm() function should change the value of my select to be "New Address".
How to do that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#shipping_customer_address option:last').prop('selected', true);
```

```js
$('#shipping_customer_address option:last').prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="shipping_address_id" id="shipping_customer_address" class="customer_address" title="" onchange="shipping.newAddress(!this.value)">
  <option value="48" selected="selected">p p, yui, cfg, 90602-1234, U.S. Minor Outlying Islands</option>
  <option value="52" selected="selected">e B, ewri, csdfwefg, 90602-1234, U.S. Minor Outlying Islands</option>
  <option value="">New Address</option>
</select>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pcaK4/1/).

Or (a *little* faster):

```
$('#shipping_customer_address option').last().prop('selected',true);
```

```js
$('#shipping_customer_address option').last().prop('selected',true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="shipping_address_id" id="shipping_customer_address" class="customer_address" title="" onchange="shipping.newAddress(!this.value)">
  <option value="48" selected="selected">p p, yui, cfg, 90602-1234, U.S. Minor Outlying Islands</option>
  <option value="52" selected="selected">e B, ewri, csdfwefg, 90602-1234, U.S. Minor Outlying Islands</option>
  <option value="">New Address</option>
</select>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pcaK4/2/).

You could simply remove the `value` attribute from the `New Address` option and select by the absence of that attribute:

```
$('#shipping_customer_address option').not('[value]').prop('selected',true);
```

```js
$('#shipping_customer_address option').not('[value]').prop('selected',true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="shipping_address_id" id="shipping_customer_address" class="customer_address" title="" onchange="shipping.newAddress(!this.value)">
  <option value="48" selected="selected">p p, yui, cfg, 90602-1234, U.S. Minor Outlying Islands</option>
  <option value="52" selected="selected">e B, ewri, csdfwefg, 90602-1234, U.S. Minor Outlying Islands</option>
  <option>New Address</option>
</select>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pcaK4/3/).

Or even select by the *empty* attribute:

```
$('#shipping_customer_address option[value=""]').prop('selected',true);
```

```js
$('#shipping_customer_address option[value=""]').prop('selected',true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="shipping_address_id" id="shipping_customer_address" class="customer_address" title="" onchange="shipping.newAddress(!this.value)">
  <option value="48" selected="selected">p p, yui, cfg, 90602-1234, U.S. Minor Outlying Islands</option>
  <option value="52" selected="selected">e B, ewri, csdfwefg, 90602-1234, U.S. Minor Outlying Islands</option>
  <option value="">New Address</option>
</select>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pcaK4/4/).

Or, in plain JavaScript, to select the last `<option>`:

```
document.getElementById('shipping_customer_address').lastElementChild.selected = true;
```

```js
document.getElementById('shipping_customer_address').lastElementChild.selected = true;
```

```html
<select name="shipping_address_id" id="shipping_customer_address" class="customer_address" title="" onchange="shipping.newAddress(!this.value)">
  <option value="48" selected="selected">p p, yui, cfg, 90602-1234, U.S. Minor Outlying Islands</option>
  <option value="52" selected="selected">e B, ewri, csdfwefg, 90602-1234, U.S. Minor Outlying Islands</option>
  <option value="">New Address</option>
</select>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pcaK4/13/).

Or, to select the last `<option>` using a CSS selector with `document.querySelector()`:

```
document.querySelector('#shipping_customer_address option:last-child').selected = true;
```

```js
document.querySelector('#shipping_customer_address option:last-child').selected = true;
```

```html
<select name="shipping_address_id" id="shipping_customer_address" class="customer_address" title="" onchange="shipping.newAddress(!this.value)">
  <option value="48" selected="selected">p p, yui, cfg, 90602-1234, U.S. Minor Outlying Islands</option>
  <option value="52" selected="selected">e B, ewri, csdfwefg, 90602-1234, U.S. Minor Outlying Islands</option>
  <option value="">New Address</option>
</select>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pcaK4/16/).

Or, for those browsers that don't recognise `lastElementChild`:

```
var options = document.getElementById('shipping_customer_address').options;

options[options.length - 1].selected = true;
```

```js
var options = document.getElementById('shipping_customer_address').options;

options[options.length - 1].selected = true;
```

```html
<select name="shipping_address_id" id="shipping_customer_address" class="customer_address" title="" onchange="shipping.newAddress(!this.value)">
  <option value="48" selected="selected">p p, yui, cfg, 90602-1234, U.S. Minor Outlying Islands</option>
  <option value="52" selected="selected">e B, ewri, csdfwefg, 90602-1234, U.S. Minor Outlying Islands</option>
  <option value="">New Address</option>
</select>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pcaK4/14/).

To select the option that has an empty `value` property/attribute using `document.querySelector()`:

```
document.querySelector('#shipping_customer_address option[value=""]').selected = true;
```

```js
document.querySelector('#shipping_customer_address option[value=""]').selected = true;
```

```html
<select name="shipping_address_id" id="shipping_customer_address" class="customer_address" title="" onchange="shipping.newAddress(!this.value)">
  <option value="48" selected="selected">p p, yui, cfg, 90602-1234, U.S. Minor Outlying Islands</option>
  <option value="52" selected="selected">e B, ewri, csdfwefg, 90602-1234, U.S. Minor Outlying Islands</option>
  <option value="">New Address</option>
</select>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pcaK4/15/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [CSS attribute-selectors (`[attribute="value"]`)](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).
  - [`:last-child` selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#last-child-pseudo).
- JavaScript:

  - [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`HTMLOptionElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement).
  - [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement).
- jQuery:

  - [`[attribute="value"]` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
  - [`last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/).
  - [`:last` selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: Thanks @David Thomas.
Clear explanation.
I chose the second one and learnt all possible ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

For this "job" to jQuery you have a lot of ways, i choose the one with `.filter()`

```
$('#shipping_customer_address option').filter(function(){return !$(this).val().length }).prop('selected','selected');
```

**edit:** now the selected option will be the one with `value=""` Check the demo

[Demo.](http://fiddle.jshell.net/stefanz/s5BUS/1/)

Comment: Thanks Stefanz.
As I said in the quesiton, I don't have access to edit the HTML element as it comes from database.

Comment: Check my edit. Now the option with empty value will be selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can search your `New Address` item and select it like this:

```
jQuery("#shipping_customer_address option:contains('New Address')").prop('selected', true);
```

See [**working demo**](http://tinker.io/39101)

---

If you just want to select the last option, instead of search for a specific item, you can do like this:

```
jQuery("#shipping_customer_address option:last").prop('selected', true);
```

See [**working demo**](http://tinker.io/37ef6)

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `prop`

```
 jQuery('#shipping_customer_address option').eq(3).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

or

```
$("#shipping_customer_address option:contains('value')").prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: It will give option which has been selected at present.
But what I want is, the selected select box option should be changed to the last option.

Comment: What happens if it has 1243 options inside select? It will get the third one

Comment: @stefanz look at the second option.First one is if Op knows the index.